Sendgrid design editor not letting me change width of button module in the HTML editor
I have two buttons side by side using the column module.
If I set the button width to 100% this is the HTML generated:
<td align="center" bgcolor="#fa883c" class="inner-td" style="border-radius:6px; font-size:16px; text-align:center; background-color:inherit;"><a href="" width="232" style="background-color:#fa883c; border:1px solid #fa883c; border-color:#fa883c; border-radius:50px; border-width:1px; color:#ffffff; display:inline-block; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:0px; line-height:normal; padding:12px 18px 12px 18px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; border-style:solid; width:270px;" target="_blank">Text</a></td>

The problem is, setting the width as 100% will output an exact value, and since box-sizing is not set to border-box, the button will overflow the container.
Moreover if I try to manually change the width to a different value, sendgrid won't let me update the module. For some reason it doesn't allow changing the width.
I need to use the button module, because of my client.
What can I do in this case?

Here's a workaround:
Adjust the padding in the button so the buttons are all the same size.
(It's annoying that each one will have to be unique, but it works.)
So: Module styles > button > padding. Toy with the width on either side of the text there.
